# Selecting cell in GridPane JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Long story short, I have 8x8 GridPane (using it as Chess Board) and I want to be able to click on each cell and get its coordinates.

```
public class BoardView {     
    private ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("board.png"));
    private GridPane boardGrid = new GridPane();

    public void createBoard(){
        boardGrid.getChildren().add(imageView);
        for(int i =0;i < 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                Tile tile = new Tile(i, j);
                GridPane.setConstraints(tile.getPane(), i, j);
                boardGrid.getChildren().add(tile.getPane());
            }
        }

    }

    class Tile {
        private int positionX;
        private int positionY;
        private Pane pane;

        Tile(int x, int y) {
            pane = new Pane();                
            positionX = x;
            positionY = y;
            pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                        System.out.println(positionX + " " + positionY);
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

However, everywhere I click, the result is "0 0", not the actual row/column position.

Comment: try setting your pane size like this pane.setPrefSize(50,50) and see if they show up

Comment: Already tried that, not working :/

Comment: You can always set `gridLinesVisible` to `true` to see what happens with everything

Comment: Well I'v done that and I can't see any lines.

Comment: I don't see where you're specifying the size for each tile's pane. They may all be 0x0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is incomplete some of your errors are :

1. You haven't give a specific size (width, height) on each Pane (Tiles)
2. I am guessing you set the size of the GridPane somewhere but its just a guess, now the way you add the background image on your Grid is something that I don't recommend instead use a StackPane.

Here is a small example which you can check to debug your problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoardView extends Application {

    // the dimensions of our background Image
    private final int BORDER_WIDTH = 695;
    private final int BORDER_HEIGHT = 720;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Load your Image
        ImageView backgroundImageView = new ImageView(
                new Image("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/24/board-157165_960_720.png"));
        // Initialize the grid
        GridPane boardGrid = initBoard();
        // Set the dimensions of the grid
        boardGrid.setPrefSize(BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_HEIGHT);

        // Use a StackPane to display the Image and the Grid
        StackPane mainPane = new StackPane();
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(backgroundImageView, boardGrid);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

    }

    private GridPane initBoard() {
        GridPane boardGrid = new GridPane();

        int tileNum = 8;
        double tileWidth = BORDER_WIDTH / tileNum;
        double tileHeight = BORDER_HEIGHT / tileNum;

        for (int i = 0; i < tileNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tileNum; j++) {
                Tile tile = new Tile(i, j);
                // Set each 'Tile' the width and height
                tile.setPrefSize(tileWidth, tileHeight);
                // Add node on j column and i row
                boardGrid.add(tile, j, i);
            }
        }
        // Return the GridPane
        return boardGrid;
    }

    class Tile extends Pane {
        private int positionX;
        private int positionY;

        public Tile(int x, int y) {
            positionX = x;
            positionY = y;
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println(positionX + " " + positionY);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

From my point of view you its more easy to handle each Tile if you made the class to extend the Pane instead of just holding a reference to it but this is just my opinion. Well the above its just an example anyway. If you cant find the problem then post a MCVE show we can help you better.